# How to find specific SSL cert with expired status?

Tags: ssl, gcloud

I have tens SSL certificate bind on a load balancer. We can view some of them were expired from GCP console and wish to export the listing to a text file.

I have run:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates list --global
```

to view all of them, and like to filter out with --filter expression.....

Unfortunately, I don't know how to find the expression for this command which can help me to filter out the expired (or some thing wrong) certificate?

Where can I get listing of expression keys that related to SSL certificate?
Or maybe some cli example to advice about --filter expression with SSL cert?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to (easily) provide the answer because I have no SSL certificates configured to test this. However, here's how you can solve the problem. If you are willing to provide a snippet of the YAML|JSON in your question, I may be able to provide more help.

Every `gcloud` command permits a flag `--log-http`. Adding this, you will be able to determine which underlying REST calls are made by the `gcloud` command. I can run this command (I just don't get useful data):

```sh
gcloud compute ssl-certificates list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--log-http
```

Yielding:

```
GET /compute/v1/projects/${PROJECT}/aggregated/sslCertificates
```

Then, using Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer), we can search on [`compute/v1`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1) to find [`sslCertificates.aggregatedList`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates/aggregatedList)

> **NOTE** `gcloud` uses the `v1` version|endpoint even though there's a `Beta` endpoint too.

Now we have the request and [response](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates/aggregatedList#response-body) types and, in fact, you can effect the REST call using the "Try this method" pane too.

The response type is useful because it's what's returned by `gcloud`. You can confirm this by using the `--format=yaml` or `--format=json` flag with the `gcloud` command:

```sh
gcloud compute ssl-certificates list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format=YAML
```

> **NOTE** I tend to use `yaml` as it's less verbose.

Now you can begin to filter and format the results.

There are several ways to do this:

##### 1. Generic

A generic way to process JSON is to use a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). There's also a similar tool for YAML called [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq).

These tools provide all-in-one mechanisms to filter and format JSON|YAML output and can be used not only with `gcloud` (just remember to use the correct `--format=json` or `--format=yaml`) flag before piping into the command.

##### 2. Proprietary (`gcloud`)

`gcloud` provides filtering, formatting and flattening. A friend wrote something of a definitive [post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/it-ops/filtering-and-formatting-fun-with) on this and I encourage to read it.

One challenge with `gcloud` is that there are 3 different mechanisms that you may need to combine:

1. [`--format`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats)
2. [`--filter`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters)
3. [`--flatten`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--flatten)